# Multiple events with one sub

Tags: vb.net, events

I have a problem with a code I written in VB.NET that use the AddHandler/RemoveHandler token.

This is the code that I have written:

```
Private Sub Remove_Handler()
    RemoveHandler txtSearch.TextChanged, AddressOf Ricarica_elenco
    RemoveHandler cbAttori.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf Ricarica_elenco
    RemoveHandler cbGeneri.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf Ricarica_elenco
    RemoveHandler cb_plex.CheckStateChanged, AddressOf Ricarica_elenco

End Sub

Private Sub Add_Handler()
    AddHandler txtSearch.TextChanged, AddressOf Ricarica_elenco
    AddHandler cbAttori.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf Ricarica_elenco
    AddHandler cbGeneri.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf Ricarica_elenco
    AddHandler cb_plex.CheckStateChanged, AddressOf Ricarica_elenco

End Sub

Private Sub Ricarica_elenco(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    CreaElenco()
End Sub
```

I have 4 events that handles one subroutine. After executing the "Add_Handler" sub, When two or more indicated events occur simultaneously, the subroutine "Ricarica_Elenco" is executed several times.

I need to create a custom event (or someelse) that collects the 4 original events and executes the procedure "Ricarica_Elenco" only once if two or more events occur simultaneously.

How can I do it?

Thanks

Marcello

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to go about this is to create a *static* boolean variable which indicate whether the method is running or not:

```
Private Sub Ricarica_elenco(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Static currentlyRunning As Boolean
    If currentlyRunning Then Exit Sub

    currentlyRunning = True
    CreaElenco()
    currentlyRunning = False
End Sub
```

You can also replace the static variable with a class-level variable if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Events don't occur simultaneously. Probably inside the *CreaElenco* method you are doing something that triggers another call to *CreaElenco* like modifying the text of *txtSearch* or modifying the current index of *cbAttori*
This is enough to trigger the call to the associated event handler and in cascade a call to *CreaElenco* while you are still processing the first call to *CreaElenco*. A simple solution is to remove the handlers before entering the *CreaElenco* method and readding them when you have finished. Of course you should be sure to always readd the handlers whatever happens inside the *CreaElenco* method. This could be accomplished adding a Try/Finally clause around the code that removes the handlers.

```
Private Sub Ricarica_elenco(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Try
        Remove_Handler()
        CreaElenco()
    Finally
        Add_Handler()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Events don't occur simultaneously" in this situation. The OP adds four handlers which call the same method. They can execute that method simultaneously, right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Adding an handler doesn't call the handler code. You need to change the Text property of _txtSearch_ via UI or code  to trigger a call to the TextChanged handler. Simultaneously means that while the engine calls the TextChanged it should call also the SelectedIndexChanged of the combo.

Comment: Oh, gotcha. I think that by "simultaneously", the OP meant that the method `CreaElenco()` gets called a second time before the first one completes.

Comment: And this is what happens I suppose. But we should look at _CreaElenco_ to be sure.